# Best way to send integers from Arduino to PHP server and JSON

Tags: mysql, json, arduino, gprs

I have a device which periodically connects to my server (www.myserver.com/counter.php) in order to read (JSON) values from my web page and display them on a LCD display.
The format is something like this:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array('number' => '23589'), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

The device reads the integer and displays it on its LCD display.

Now, I want to change the integer displayed by the PHP page by using my Arduino (already configured to communicate over a network).

What is the best way to do that?
I was thinking to store the values sent by Arduino in a MySQL database and then read them from my PHP page by encoding them with JSON.

Is there any other faster way?
Do you have suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Or I could make Arduino to write on a TXT file stored on the server and then read it from my PHP code. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Arduino can send a `get` of the number to a PHP page, and PHP can store it in a global variable.
Though, if you want it to be saved somewhere you can use MySQL or a simple text file (with adequate access restrictions due to how you want to utilize it), as you mentioned at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hossein, I used the `get` method to send the integer to a PHP page in order to store it into a database. Then, the main PHP web reads this integer and encode it for JSON.